# angucomplete-alt angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть проблема при попытке прикрутить к remote-api-handler ответ от API запроса который объявлен с помощью $resource

```
$scope.search = function (userInputString, timeoutPromise) {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:1337/api/group'); // работает
    return restApi.Group.all().$promise; // не работает
};
```

Пока писал этот вопрос, посмотрел в исходники библиотеки, и оказалось проблема в различии объектов которые возвращают $resourse и $http в случае успеха.

```
$resuorce(...)..$promise.then(successHandler);
$http(...).then(successHandler);

var successHandler = function (res) {
    // для $resuorce данные будут сразу в res
    // для $http что бы получить данные нужно обратиться к res.data
}
```

В случае данной библиотеки обращение происходит как во втором варианте, в итоге undefined, и пустой список.

Может есть какой-то способ обойти это? Пока что не нашел ничего

[Ссылка на плагин angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt)

Answer (score 1):

Использовал такой костыль в файле **angucomplete-alt.js**, строка 399.

```
var responseData = (!res.status && !res.headers && !res.config) ? res : res.data;
```

Вместо условия ниже..)

```
  // normalize return obejct from promise
  if (!status && !headers && !config) {
    responseData = responseData.data;
  }
```